# ¿Cómo guardar y descargar una archivo en C# mvc?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Deseo saber como es la manera correcta de guardar archivo con su extensión en la base de datos en bytes. Y cual es la manera correcta de descargar la misma desde base de datos.

El problema es que cuando descargo el archivo se guarda un tipo de archivo desconocido con una banderita de window como si no estuviera definido la extensión del archivo que se registro en la base de datos.

Todos los métodos mostrados funcionan.

Mi método registrar que guarda la imagen.

```
public JsonResult registrarTicket(Ticket ticket)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase filebase = Request.Files[0];
            WebImage image = new WebImage(filebase.InputStream);
            ticket.Imagen = image.GetBytes();
            ticket.Fecha_Reg = DateTime.Now;
            ticket.Area = "DESARROLLO";
            ticket.Est_ticket = "Registrado";
            ticket.Flag_est = true;

            this._repo.Agregar(ticket);
            this._repo.Guardar();
            return Json(new { data = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Mi método para descargar la imagen

```
public JsonResult obtenerImagen(int numTicket)
        {
            var obj = _repo.TraerUno(numTicket);
            byte[] imagen = obj.Imagen;
            Session["Archivo"] = imagen;
            return Json(new { data = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); ;
        }

        public FileResult descargar()
        {
            var ms = Session["Archivo"] as byte[];
            var filename = string.Format("Imagen{0:yyyyMMdd_hhmmss}", DateTime.Now);
            //var cadena = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms);
            return File(ms, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, filename);

        }
```

Estoy trabajando con ajax

```
descargar: function () {
            var ticketId = $("#Num_ticket").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "../Ticket/obtenerImagen",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { numTicket: ticketId},
                success: function (result) {
                    window.location = "../Ticket/descargar";
                }, error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            })
        },
```

Comment: ¿Dónde está especificado el nombre del archivo? El tercer parámetro de `File` debería ser el nombre, pero en vez de eso estás codificando el contenido del archivo. ¿Porqué le intentas enviar el contenido del archivo dos veces a `File`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult

Comment: Envio 2 veces file porque uso ajax y ello me pide devolver un valor en success.

Comment: Lo de dos veces era porque enviabas el contenido como el nombre. Igual, enviar el contenido del archivo dos veces no suena para nada una buena idea. ¿Y si pesa 500 MB? Aunque no veo que lo estés haciendo. ¿Qué problema tiene tu código actualizado? Aquí tienes cómo hacerlo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670209/download-excel-file-via-ajax-mvc